# How to test hash order equivalence in rspec should_receive .with matchers?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Ruby has ordered hashes, yet does not test for ordering when testing for equivalence. The usual way to test hash equivalence with ordering is `hash1.to_a == hash2.to_a`. However, in rspec should_receive .with matchers, you seem stuck with testing regular equivalence. There are workarounds, like adding another method to MyClass that supplies what gets stored in ordered_hash and testing the .to_a of that, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner or more idiomatic way of testing ordered equivalence of hashes with rspec should_receive .with.

```
class MyClass
  def self.ordering
    [:v_1, :v_2]
  end

  def self.foo(unordered_hash)
    ordered_hash = unordered_hash.sort_by{|key, _| ordering.index(key)}.to_h
    bar(ordered_hash)
  end

  def self.bar(ordered_hash)
  end
end

unordered_hash = {v_2: 2, v_1: 1}
# would succeed even though it actually received {v_1: 1, v_2: 2}
MyClass.should_receive(:bar).with({v_2: 2, v_1: 1})
MyClass.foo(unordered_hash)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember `should_receive` accepts the block to test more complex tests on arguments, like:

```
MyClass.should_receive(:bar) { |ordered_hash|
  ordered_hash.to_a.should == {v_2: 2, v_1: 1}.to_a
}
```

Comment: This works, but I want to add that if you have any rescues for standarderror around `bar` in your code, any rspec expectation failures would be caught by those rescues and your test will always be green. To avoid this, capture the the received values inside the block and set expectations on them outside the block.